# Cancel Button makes a selection rather than cancelling

Tags: vba, button, outlook, userform

I'm using the following code behind an Outlook UserForm called Select_Email_Template.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Account Amendment Non SC"
    .AddItem "Account Amendment SC Application Received"
    .AddItem "Account Amendment SC"
    .AddItem "Account Creation Non SC"
    .AddItem "Account Creation SC Application Received"
    .AddItem "Account Creation SC"
    .AddItem "Export Function"
    .AddItem "Password Reset"
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    lstNum = ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    Unload Select_Email_Template
End Sub
```

The ComboBox allows the user to select an email template. When one is selected and <kbd>OK</kbd> clicked, the template is opened in Outlook.

This is the code which opens the templates:

```
Public lstNum As Long

Public Sub Email_Templates()

    Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Select_Email_Template.Show

    Select Case lstNum

    ' Following the listbox entries


    Case 0
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment Non SC.oft")

    Case 1
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment SC Application Received.oft")

    Case 2
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment SC.oft")

    Case 3
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Creation Non SC.oft")

    Case 4
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Creation SC Application Received.oft")

    Case 5
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Creation SC.oft")

    Case 6
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Export Function.oft")

    Case 7
        Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Export Function.oft")

    End Select

    ' Use for a specific purpose not randomly
    ' On Error Resume Next

    With outMail
        .Display
    End With

    ' On Error GoTo 0

cleanup:
        Set outMail = Nothing

  End Sub
```

When the user clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd>, the form closes but the first template from the list opens in Outlook.

How can I close the form without this first template opening at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst it *is* possible to solve the issue by using a global variable, a much neater solution is use the `UserForm.Tag` property to pass a result back to the main procedure.

Be aware that unloading the UserForm also removes the tag value, so you need to *hide* the UserForm in the click handlers, use the tag value in the main procedure, and *then* unload the UserForm.

`Select_Email_Template` UserForm code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  Dim varTemplateName As Variant

  With ComboBox1
    For Each varTemplateName In Templates(NameOnly:=True) ' Templates() also works
      .AddItem varTemplateName
    Next
  End With

End Sub

Private Sub btnOK_Click()
  Me.Tag = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
  Me.Tag = -1
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = VBA.VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    btnCancel_Click
  End If
End Sub
```

Non-Class Module code:

```
Public Sub Email_Templates()
  With Select_Email_Template
    .Show
    If .Tag <> -1 Then
      CreateItemFromTemplate(Templates(.Tag, FullPath:=True)).Display ' Templates(.Tag) also works
    End If
  End With
  Unload Select_Email_Template
End Sub

Public Function Templates _
                ( _
                  Optional ByVal plngIndex As Long = -1 _
                , Optional ByVal NameOnly As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal FullPath As Boolean = False _
                ) _
       As Variant

  Const strcTemplatesDir As String = "<TemplatesPath>\"
  Const strcTemplateExtension As String = ".oft"

  Static avarTemplateNames As Variant

  If IsEmpty(avarTemplateNames) Then
    avarTemplateNames = Array _
    ( _
      "Account Amendment Non SC" _
    , "Account Amendment SC Application Received" _
    , "Account Amendment SC" _
    , "Account Creation Non SC" _
    , "Account Creation SC Application Received" _
    , "Account Creation SC" _
    , "Export Function" _
    , "Export Function" _
    )
  End If
  If plngIndex <> -1 Then
    If NameOnly = True And FullPath = False Then
      Templates = avarTemplateNames(plngIndex)
    Else
      Templates = strcTemplatesDir & avarTemplateNames(plngIndex) & strcTemplateExtension
    End If
  Else
    Templates = avarTemplateNames
  End If

End Function
```

**Explanation:**

The main idea here is to return, via the `Select_Email_Template.Tag` property, a -1 when the user clicks <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and a valid index (0 to 7 in your example) when the user clicks <kbd>OK</kbd>.

The code also redirects <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, clicking the close box (and its keyboard shortcut equivalent <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPC</kbd>;<kbd>C</kbd>), and any other method of closing the UserForm, to the cancel button's click handler.

I've also taken the liberty of refactoring your code so all the template data is declared once only and in one place only, i.e., in the `Templates()` function.

I've used a static variable in this function so that the array is only ever initialized once. You could just declare it with `Dim` and skip the empty check and it would still work just fine.

---

> Note: If you are curious about my variable naming convention, it is based on [RVBA](http://www.xoc.net/standards/rvbanc.asp).

Comment: Hi @robinCTS, thank you so much for putting this together and for the explanation. It works perfectly.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 2):

@IRHM I've got the following to work correctly. I've used MsgBoxes to test with, and tested each option. Try it. Once it looks like it's working for you, comment out or delete the unnecessary stuff, change the variable names and you should be good to go.

```
Sub Email_Templates()
Dim ComboBox1
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim intSelectedIndex As Integer
Dim myNum As Integer

'Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem

Userform1.Show

myNum = Userform1.ComboBox1.ListIndex

If myNum = 0 Then
  Goto Abort
Else

MsgBox ("Back to the main module")

 Select Case myNum

 Case 1
    'Using MsgBox to test and make sure it's working
    MsgBox "You selected Account Amendment Non SC - Option 1"
    'Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment Non SC.oft")

Case 2
    MsgBox "You selected Account Amendment SC Application Received - Option 2"
    'Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment SC Application Received.oft")

Case 3
    MsgBox "You Selected Account Amendment SC - Option 3"
    'Set outMail = CreateItemFromTemplate("TemplatePath\Account Amendment SC.oft")
End Select
Abort:
 End If
 Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

Put the following lines in the UserForm code module:

```
Sub btnCancel_Click()
  MsgBox ("Cancel button selected")
  Unload Me
End Sub

Sub btnOK_Click()
  MsgBox ("OK Selected")
  Me.Hide
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Put all your AddItems here
  With ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .AddItem "This should exit", 0
    .AddItem "Selection 1", 1
    .AddItem "Selection 2", 2
    .AddItem "Selection 3", 3
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Mitch thank you for putting this together.

I've put all the code in the Userform module, but unfortunately the problem still occurs.

Many thanks and regards

Comment: @IRHM the only other thing I can think of is, in the properties of the userform buttons (Cancel button), Set the "Cancel" field to "True"

Comment: Hi @Mitch, thank you for coming back to me with this. Unfortunately when I do this, the OK button no longer functions.

Kind Regards

Comment: @IRHM I've been working on this all day. I've tried your code, modified it, still getting the same results. It has something to do with calling the userform and then returning to the script. Cancelling the userform just closes the form and returns to the script, Select Case lstNum picks up at that point with a value of 0, that's why it keeps choosing the first option.

Comment: @IRHM I've got a working example posted. Please test. I think you'll be happy. Well, no one else had responded when i went to post this, then I see 2 other really good answers.

Comment: While this does work, the `This should exit` string is a bit ugly. I would suggest `None` as a better alternative. Or even `Please select a template`.

Comment: @robinCTS No argument here. It was just something I used while testing to make sure it was doing what I wanted it to. Actually the whole damn thing is pretty ugly, but works. Pretty much most of my stuff is that way. I would not say I'm a programmer, and certainly not a hacker, but more of a hack than anything. At 62, functionality overrides aesthetics. (Grin). I actually voted for your solution. Regards. -mm

Answer (score 2):

The global variable lstnum is initially 0. Since you are using lstnum as the Select trigger make it -1, to conform to the norm.

[Outlook Form To Select Email Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322263/outlook-form-to-select-email-template)

```
Case -1
'  -1 is what you want to use if nothing is selected
```

Following the method you are using to return the choice from the userform.

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    lstNum = -1
    Unload Select_Email_Template
End Sub
```